# Ways to Scale glBitmap

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-3

I have been using glBitmap for quite a long time and I need to scale according to the Windows Display settings. For me, performance is key and I can't afford texture spriting or any other stuff.

glPixelZoom only works with glDrawPixels, so I decided to migrate from glBitmap to glDrawPixels
assuming that both glBitmap and glDrawPixels will have equivalent performance.

so I use glDrawPixels with type = GL_BITMAP and format = GL_COLOR_INDEX but pixels are black.
glBitmap uses glColor as pixel color but I don't find how I can make it work for glDrawPixels.

I am aware of the possibility of generating actual RGB pixels out of glBitmap but I am trying to find a straightforward approach that glDrawPixels draw using current glColor maybe using some pixel map operations?

Is it possible?

Comment: "*For me, performance is key*" If that's true, why are you using `glBitmap`, which is an *atrociously* slow function? `glPixelZoom` and `glDrawPixels` are similarly not known for performance, nor are `GL_COLOR_INDEX` images. Modern, high-performance OpenGL wouldn't use something like that.

Comment: I have to maintain the old code, some softwares were dispatched around 1990 and they use old opengl

Comment: If you're able to migrate from `glBitmap` to `glDrawPixels`, why would you be unable to migrate to "upload to a texture and render it using a shader?"

Comment: There's a dedicated old render engine without any shader support and I don't think I would be able to add shader architecture in the old engine and many tests will break if  there's a 1-pixel mismatch in pixel rasterization

Comment: Did you try using a texture or did you just assume that it's going to be slow?

Comment: No I didnt try, I am more worried about pixel displacement than performance, glBitmap uses glRasterPos which takes care of model view matrix and with xorg, yorg, I am already facing issues to have correct raster position and I want to make minimum changes